# Cassandra Read Load Varies among nodes?

Tags: database, cassandra, cassandra-2.1

I have a 2 DC(each 2 node) cluster. The `two data-centers(DC1,DC2)` are about 5000 km apart.

For one of the datacenters(DC1), the number of read requests are about 10 times the other node. The load policy used is `Token Aware(DC Aware Round Robin)`.

When I try to make queries from devcenter, the load is balanced among the two nodes in DC1. Gossip is normal among the nodes. 
The snitch used is `GossipPropertyFileSnitch`.

The variable phi_convict_threshold is 12 in the yaml. What could be the problem. Any direction you may think is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Why did you set `phi_convict_threshold` to 0.1 ? The usual value is 8 and for cloud deployments (AWS for ex) it's recommended to set it to 12.

The lower the `phi_convict_threshold` is set, the more false positive gossip protocol will mark a node as being DOWN

Comment: I am really sorry but  that variable was dynamic_snitch_badness_threshold.. phi_convict_threshold is 12..